# Use Path Parameters in AWS Amplify REST API (Javascript)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I need to call an endpoint using path parameters, something like `/user/{id}`
I'm not able to find anything like in the documentation of Amplify but I found this [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3357).

It seems that the feature has been merged on February 21st but I see a "pending-review" tag so I don't know if this feature is available.

Any help would be welcome.
Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used Amplify to set up a lambda function for the API, you can do the following for a get.

**Local**

```js
try {
    const { user, error } = await API.get(
      API_NAME,
      `/user-details?name=${ name }&email=${ email }&number=${ userNumber }`
    )
    if ( error ) return { dbError: error }
    else return { user: user }
  } catch( error ) { return { dbError: error } }
```

**Lambda**

```js
/**
 * Get a specific user's details.
 */
app.get( `/user-details`, async ( request, response ) => {
  const params = request.query
  ...
  response.json( { statusCode: 200, user: DATA_RETRIEVED } )
}
```

You can use a similar method for posting as well.

**Local**

```js
try {
  const { tos, error } = await API.post(
    API_NAME,
    `/tos`,
    { body: {
      name: user.name.replace( ` `, `\ ` ),
      email: user.email,
      number: user.userNumber,
      version: version.toISOString()
    } }
  )
  if ( error ) console.log( `error`, error )
  return { user: user }
} catch( error ) console.log( `errored`, error )
```

**Lambda**

```js
/**
 * Adds a terms of service to a user.
 */
app.post( `/tos`, async ( request, response ) => {
  const params = request.body
  ...
  response.json( { statusCode: 200, tos: DATA_RETRIEVED } )
}
```